# Filter blur support for Windows Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-filters

I've got a div that covers a bunch of content that I'd like to blur out when user authentication is required.

Installed Safari for Windows to test my site. Version 5.1.7 seems to be the latest.

Just wondering if Safari  supports CSS filter blur? At one stage I thought I had it going but I changed something and it seems to have disappeared, now I'm second guessing myself that I actually saw it working at all.

I know Opera's blur only works if you have a div position set to absolute or fixed. Is there something special for Safari that I've overlooked?

The [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) site only lists Safari Mac and iOS support

This is my CSS class:

```
.login_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-filter  : blur(10px);
    -moz-filter : blur(10px);
    -ms-filter  : blur(10px);
    -o-filter   : blur(10px);
    filter      : blur(10px);    
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use Safari for Windows to test your site - it has not been updated since May 2012 & is hugely behind Safari Mac/iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari 5 does not support CSS3 filters, neither unprefixed nor with a `-webkit-` prefix. As shown on caniuse.com, support started in version 6, which was never made available for Windows as Apple discontinued Safari for Windows after version 5.1.7.